# how to call API using asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0

I'm using .net 6 to call API and output data from View

is it possible to call the API using asp mvc

i am generating a url from appsetting.json

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },

  "ServiceUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
}
```

then i call the url from the repository and execute it

```
public class BannerService : IBannerAPI
    {
        public static readonly string serviceUrl = Setting.ServiceUrl;
        //public static readonly string provinceID = Setting.ProvinceID;

        public static T CallAPI<T>(string method, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient(serviceUrl);

                var request = new RestRequest(method, Method.Get);
                if(parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach(var param in parameters )
                    {
                        request.AddParameter(param.Key, param.Value);
                    }
                }
                var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content)!;
            }
            catch(Exception e) { 
                LogManager.LogException(e);
                return default(T)!;
            }
        }
        public List<BannerModel> GetBanner()
        {
            return CallAPI<List<BannerModel>>("GetBanner", null);
        }
    }
```

It id IBannerAPI

```
   public interface IBannerAPI
    {
        List<BannerModel> GetBanner();
    }
```

It id BannerModel

```
    public class BannerModel
    {
        public string BannerID { get; set; }
        public string? NgayTao { get; set; }
        public string? TieuDeBanner { get; set; }
        public string? HinhAnhBanner { get; set; }
        public string? STTUuTien { get; set; }
        public string HoatDong { get; set; }
    }
```

but i can't pass data to view the old way, i have a sample and it says to use script

how can you help me get API data, if you guys have other way to call API then help me. Please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP9SC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3eHv.png)

Comment: the error message is clear, you are trying to deserialze an list/array of json objects into a single onject, it needs to be desserialzed into a list

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite make out whether your issue lies within deserializing your response or in using that response to build a view. If you could be so kind, please provide the raw response and the error message. I'll adjust my answer later, if relevant. I'll make it a bit more generic for now.

I don't have much experience with the RestClient class, my first question is: are you intentionally using a class that runs synchronously instead of asynchronously? If not, then I'd recommend using HttpClient instead as described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) and implement it as follows:

In Startup.cs

`services.AddHttpClient<IBannerClient, BannerClient>()`

In BannerService (which I'd recommend you to call BannerClient as it should be separate from your Banner-object business logic if that is relevant)

```
public class BannerClient : IBannerClient
{
    public async Task<List<Banner>> GetBannersAsync()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{Settings.ServiceUrl}/your/route/here");
        var result = new List<Banner>();
            try
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
                var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Banner>>(responseString);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                // handle error
            }
            return result;
    }
}
```

If you're set on using RestClient then I'd check the following:

`var request = new RestRequest(method, Method.Get);`

I think calling this the method is a bit confusing, rather call it `route` or `uri`.  Can you confirm that the url on the rest client is set correctly? (Small note: you don't have to set the actual method to Get as that seems to be the default)

Also, what drew my attention:

`return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content)!;`

I see an exclamation mark after this statement, what does that do?

EDIT:

Based on the response you posted, it seems like your datamodel doesn't match the JSON coming back which leads to an error in deserialization. The JSON Deserializer matches based on best-effort (can be manipulated by attributes as I'll show you) so it tries to find a property called "data" to bind to, but doesn't find it in your model. You should structure you class like so:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Exact.Office365.TeamsApp.Model
{
    public class BannersReponse
    {
        // Here's a way to influence the property it tries to bind to
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public List<Banner> Banners { get; set; }
    }

    public class Banner
    {
        public bool HoatDong { get; set; }

        public string NgayTao { get; set; }

        public string STTUuTien { get; set; }

        public string BannerID {get; set; }

        public string TieuDeBanner { get; set; }
        
        public string HinhAnhBanner {get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank, i using .net6 it doesn't have a startup, i put some erros on no starting from "catch(Exception e)"

Comment: @NguyễnLêNguyên put the StartUp code in Program.cs

Comment: That `!` is a [null forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) - to signal the compiler that you know this will never return a `null`

Comment: @NguyễnLêNguyên if you want you can still use Startup in .NET 6, they just removed it to make it more script-like to make it easier for small projects to start. Based on your error it seems like the response JSON doesn't "fit" the List<BannerModel> format. Does your response follow the following format?
[
 {
  "BannerID": "",
  "NgayTao":"",
  //etc
 }
]

Also make sure the response is successful by checking response.IsSuccessStatusCode. Trying to deserialize an error response to your model might be the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the data, I'll update my answer